# Characters to pinyin for names?

Tags: pinyin

I am aware that there are some difficulties in automatic conversion of characters to pinyin, because the same character can be pronounced in different ways depending on the context.  Do these problems still exist if you just want to convert personal names?  Are there any good software tools for that job?

Comment: It is right. Sometimes we need to ask him/herself to know the exact pronounce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names are still tricky. There was even a heated discussion recently about the correct pronunciation of a very famous person called 甄嬛.

Some characters are neither wrong nor right, e.g.: 茜 some people pronounce it xi1 other pronounce it qian4 ... it just depends on their parents

Haven't tired any of these but there's a bunch of different software that will do this:

中英文姓名批量转换器

韦氏港台拼音姓名批量转换器

etc etc

but any software will still need people to proofread it & maybe even confirm it with the people themselves...