# How can I find the Chinese meaning and possible characters for a Pinyin name (without tone marks)

Tags: simplified-characters, names, surnames

I am trying to find out the Mandarin characters and the meaning behind a name,
Most web sites I go to have very generic answers, if they answer at all.

This thread doesn't answer my question [Characters to pinyin for names?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/7171/characters-to-pinyin-for-names)

I have tried various websites but no luck as yet.

Any suggestions would be kindly appreciated

Comment: No. Even with exact pinyin and tone, we can only guess one out of the many words that have the same pronunciation. For example: 燕彥艷(yàn); 文聞(wén); 炆玟(wén/mín).

Comment: What is the name? Many names are fairly common. Someone here will know the name!